# Javascript return illegal statement

Tags: javascript, return

```
if(choice1 === choice2) {
return"The result is a tie!";
```

}

else if (choice1 === "rock") {

```
if (choice2 === "scissors") {
    return "rock wins";

}
else {
    return "paper wins";
}
```

}

please help mee

Comment: Problem is: illegal return statement

Comment: `return` should be used inside a function

Comment: What are you trying to return to? You may only return to a function

Answer (score 1):

A *return* statement returns control to the calling context. In the case of global code, there is no calling context to return to, so they are illegal there. They are part of the production for *FunctionDeclaration*, so you can only use them inside functions.

To get to the relevant parts of ECMA-262, start with [§14.1 Function Definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions), one of which is [*FunctionDeclaration*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-FunctionDeclaration) which consists of, among other things, a [*FunctionBody*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-FunctionBody), which is made up of a [*FunctionStatementList*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-FunctionStatementList), which contains a [*StatementList*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-StatementList). Now that is made up (surprisingly) of zero or more [*StatementListItem*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-StatementListItem)s which are [*Statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-Statement)s, and one type of statement is [*ReturnStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ReturnStatement), which is [described in §13.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-return-statement).

So return statements can only appear in function bodies, and function bodies can only appear in code that is a FunctionDeclaration, [*FunctionExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-FunctionExpression) or [*ArrowFunction*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ArrowFunction). So from that it can be stated more generally that return statements can only appear inside functions.